# strings command in command line tool is not doing anything

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, appstore-sandbox

I'm trying to push my code to apple. I am at the stage of validating my code in Xcode. 
I am following along this post: 
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution_overview/publishing_to_the_app_store/

But I receive an error saying "The app reference non-public selectors /myproject/path:artwork, command, finished, initWithSendPort[image]

I have read that some says to run the command line tool in xcode against the dll to find the culprit like so:

```
strings /path/to/dllfolder.dll  | grep artwork
```

but my app doesn't have any dll in it. After doing build against my configuration in Xamarin, the receiving folder only has myapp, myapp.dsym, myapp.exe, my app.xcent and the resources folder which is empty.

I'm stuck. What should I do?

SOLUTION:

@Rolf, I will mark your answer as the solution because part of it is what I did to solve the problem. I downloaded the latest Xamarin update, version 3.0 and then did "link all assemblies" and it worked right away.

Comment: `.dll`? That's a windows file extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These selectors most likely show up inside monotouch.dll. However most of these selectors are in fact documented publicly [1], those that aren't have been removed (from your list I believe `initWithSendPort:receivePort:components` is the only one) from future versions of Xamarin.iOS.

The current workaround is to enable the managed linker in the project's iOS Build options (set "Linker Behavior" to "Link all assemblies" or "Link SDK assemblies only"). This will remove unused code from monotouch.dll, and unless you actually use the API in question, the usage of these selectors will be removed.

[1] http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/59264/#Comment_59264

Answer (score 0):

Use this option to strings:

´´´
 -a
 --all
       -   Do not scan only the initialized and loaded sections of object
       files; scan the whole files.
´´´

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strings&sektion=1&n=1